# Can someone re-write this code without any error

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this code in python 3.5

```
temp=0
def add1(x):
    f=12
    if temp < x:
        for i in range(20):
            temp=temp + f
            print(temp)
add1(21)


Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in
 <module>
     add1(12)   File "<pyshell#28>", line 3, in add1
     if temp < x: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'temp' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you meant `temp` to be a local variable inside `add1`:

```
def add1(x):
    temp=0 # Here!
    f=12
    if temp < x:
        for i in range(20):
            temp=temp + f
            print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `temp` variable as an argument in your function so it can be properly used by it and modified without producing any errors. Also it is good practice to use different names for global variables and function parameters. Your code should look like this:

```
tempglobal=0

def add1(x, tempparam):
    f=12
    if tempparam< x:
        for i in range(20):
            tempparam=tempparam+ f
            print(tempparam)

add1(21, tempglobal)
```